# 3D Plane in a discrete domain.

Tags: 3d

I have a 3D plane defined by 3 floating points. I determine the plane equation parameters (a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0). I want to test all integer points (x,y,z) of the domain if them are in the plane.
I have to verify the equation a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0. But because (x,y,z) are discrete the equation could not be fulfill by any point. How can I find "delta" in order that '|a*x+b*y+c*z+d| < delta' in order to find a plane with only one layer of points.

Thanks,

Luís Gonçalves

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How do you define a layer?

Comment: Layer - A plane with one point thick.

Comment: I think that is not an accurate enough definition of "layer". If the plane has an irrational "slope", it may approach grid points to any degree, so even an infinitesimal  $\Delta$ will have some points nearby.